# Secure a SD-CARD and access it through app

Tags: android, encryption, react-native

I have classified data in my SD-CARD. Is there any way to give access to the SD-CARD only through the app(**react-native-project**) ? File involved is **.mp4** files.

Most of the solutions that i have found were about encrypting the data within the SD-CARD using AES-Encryption. But i am dealing with large files, therefore decrypting the entire file at once will throw `memory out exception`.

Secondly, Reading entire data stream-by-stream is a possibility, when i tested this method out the first set of stream(encrypted) will get successfully decrypted. The next stream will result in the error `Malformed UTF-8 data`.

Thirdly, I have tried dividing the file into pieces, decrypting each piece and appending each them to make a expected file. I am getting issues as specified here [Issue Description](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/issues/680).

**EDIT:**

Package Used for encryption: [simple-crypto-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-crypto-js),

Function to decrypt file stream-by-stream:

```
 decryptfile() {
RNFetchBlob.fs
  .readStream(
    RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DCIMDir + "/encrypted.dat",
    "base64",
    4194303,
    30000      // 30 seconds buffer time before next stream comes
  )
  .then(stream => {
    let data = "";
    stream.open();
    stream.onData(chunk => {
      data += chunk;
      var decipherText = simpleCrypto.decrypt(chunk.toString());// First set of chunk will get successfully decrypted, the next chunk will result to Malformed UTF-8 data error
      this.writeOriginal(decipherText);
    });
    stream.onEnd(() => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  });
 }
```

Function to append data:

```
writeOriginal(decipherText) {
RNFetchBlob.fs
  .appendFile(
    RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DCIMDir + "/encrypt.mp4",
    decipherText,
    "base64"
  )
  .then(() => {

    console.log("File Written");
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("file writing error", error);
  });
}
```

This is a Offline learning application where videos are stored in an SD Card and accessed in app.

Comment: It's not very clear what you want from this question. Set a password on the SD? Fix your coding problems, but where is the code?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, Thanks for commenting, i have reframed  my question. I basically want a way to secure my SD-Card and access it via my app.

Comment: AES is a block cipher with a block size of 16 bytes. Therefore you don't have to process the whole file at one. You can process it in blocks of 16 bytes. Every good programming language provides also cipher streams that allows to decrypt data while reading/writing it. I assume also react-native provides such an interface. The plain Android API does support it.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question unfortunately. I do think you fixed most of the issues to the question though. But please note that this library was created to simply  encrypt JS objects. It was not designed to encrypt files. It does indicate the library used to create the functionality; possibly that library includes the required, lower level functionality?

Comment: I got it working @Robert. Your comment gave me insights to proceed further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packages used are [rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob) & [simple-crypto-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-crypto-js)

> Stream-by-Stream Encryption and writing in memory:

```
RNFetchBlob.fs
        .readStream(res.uri, "base64", 4194304, 4000)
        .then(stream => {
          let data = "";
          stream.open();
          stream.onData(chunk => {
            data += chunk;
            var cipherText = simpleCrypto.encrypt(chunk);
            RNFetchBlob.fs
              .appendFile(
                RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DCIMDir + "/encryptfile1.dat",
                cipherText,
                "base64"
              )
              .then(data => {
                console.log("file written", data); // gives buffer size use it for reading while decrypting
              })
              .catch(error => {
                console.log("file writing error", error);
              });
          });
          stream.onEnd(() => {
            console.log(data.length);
          });
        });
```

> Stream-by-Stream Decryption:

```
RNFetchBlob.fs
  .readStream(
    RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DCIMDir + "/encryptfile1.dat",
    "base64",
    5592464,
    4000
  )
  .then(stream => {
    let data = "";
    stream.open();
    stream.onData(chunk => {
      data += chunk;
      var decipherText = simpleCrypto.decrypt(chunk.toString());
      this.writeOriginal(decipherText);
    });
    stream.onEnd(() => {
      this.setState({ playvideo: !this.state.playvideo });
      console.log("file decrypted");
    });
  });
```

> Function to append decrypted base64 and generate .mp4 file:

```
writeOriginal(decipherText) {
RNFetchBlob.fs
  .appendFile(
    RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DCIMDir + "/encryptfile2.mp4",
    decipherText,
    "base64"
  )
  .then(() => {
    console.log("File Written");
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("file writing error", error);
  });
}
```

Comment: does your large videos get encryted into multiple dat files? how do you decrypt and combine them into one mp4 later on?